# Как реализовать обмен данными между CustomView и Activity?

Tags: android, customview

Я создал `CustomView`, которая сама умеет обрабатывать жесты `onScroll` и `onFling` (внутри View за это отвечает `Scroller` и `computescroll()`), то есть если я вытащу эту `View` в activity_main.xml, то она будет реагировать и на `onScroll` и на `onFling`, даже без объявления этого `View` в MainActivity.java .
Также эта `View` содержит публичные методы (допустим `getX()` и `getY()`), которые возвращают на сколько было сдвинуто содержимое `View`.

Проблема заключается в том, что я не знаю как в MainActivity считывать значения `getX()` и `getY()` тогда, когда изменился scroll в моей `View`.

Следует добавить, что в основном макете activity_main.xml будет два таких `View` + ещё куча кнопок.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для передачи данных используйте `interface`.

В `CustomView`:

```
SendData sendData;    
interface SendData{
    void sendData(int data);
}

public CustomView(Context ctx, ...){
    ...
    try {
        sendData = (SendData) ctx;
    } catch (ClassCastExeption e){
    } 
}
```

В `MainActivity`

```
class MainActivity implements CustomView.SendData { 
...

@Overrride 
void sendData (int data) {
... ваша обработка data
}
```

Использование (в нужном месте `CustomView`), например:

```
@Override
protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
    super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
    sendData.setData(getY()); <== передача
}
```